# learnyounode #9 juggling async, can official solution break?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, race-condition

So I am learning node.js right now and have done some multitasking before and my concept is that async and multitasking have many similar isses, which brings me to my question.

The official solution for this problem is:

```
  var http = require('http')
    var bl = require('bl')
    var results = []
    var count = 0

    function printResults () {
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        console.log(results[i])
    }

    function httpGet (index) {
      http.get(process.argv[2 + index], function (response) {
        response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
          if (err)
            return console.error(err)

          results[index] = data.toString()
          //AREA OF INTEREST START
          count++

          if (count == 3)
            printResults()
          //AREA OF INTEREST END
        }))
      })
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      httpGet(i)
```

Notice the part in the 'AREA OF INTEREST' comments. Is it not possible for something like a race condition to occur here causing the printResults function to be called multiple times?

for example, all three 'end' callbacks come simultaneously, each executes `count++` one after the other (so the `count == 3` check has not happened yet on any callback but count has been increment thrice) now each of them will check the `count == 3` condition, which will be true for all thus calling `printResults` thrice

Is this possible and the official solution is somewhat flawed or am i misunderstanding some concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a race condition is not a problem for that code. The callbacks run in a single thread. They will not run all at once in parallel. They will run in series.

For more information on how callbacks are queued up and why there is no race condition in the code, you may choose to watch [a great video by Philip Roberts called "What the heck is the event loop anyway?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).

Comment: Thanks man. though the video was 30 min long and I didn't have time to watch it (though might watch it later) but it gave me an idea of what to search for and read this instead: http://book.mixu.net/node/ch2.html